# Form data request header has wrong format

Tags: reactjs, http

I have this http get request which sends some data to a local server. In the dev tools i see this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhFJ9.png) which is the wrong format and server cant read it properly. The correct one would be:

> fullname : george
>       phone: xxxxxx

What do i do wrong?

```
  const form = new FormData();
    form.append("fullname","george");
    form.append("phone","xxxxxx");
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      body: form
    }).then((res)=>{

        console.log(res)

    });
```

Comment: change 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to 'Content-Type': 'application/json'  and try again

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi but form data are not in json format. Right?

Comment: Right, but send as json to server, body: JSON.stringify(form)

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi But i dont want to send it as json.